# Change the font of \mathrm and functions such as \cos \sin, \sup

Tags: fonts

My document has `ptm` as `\rmdefault` and math is typeset using MTpro2. I would like to change the font of the upright characters for mathematics to match the font used in the body of the document. For example, anything written as `\mathrm{cos}` or `\cos` should use the same font as the body of the document.

That way I could stop using `\text{cos}` whenever I want upright letters in the math which matches the font used for the body, which is annoying.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` is not sufficient for the purposes of math.

Load `mathptmx` before `mtpro2` or, even better, `newtxtext`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\let\hbar\relax % a fix for not getting a spurious error
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\cos$

$\mathrm{cos}$

$\text{cos}$
\end{document}
```

The following is my recommended version with `newtxtext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\cos$

$\mathrm{cos}$

$\text{cos}$
\end{document}
```

[image]